# How to mock http header in MockRestServiceServer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I'm using `MockRestServiceServer` to mock an external webservice xml response.
That already works fine, but how can I also mock the **http header** inside the response, not only the response body?

```
    @MockBean
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private MockRestServiceServer mockServer;

    @Before
    public void createServer() throws Exception {
        mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        String xml = loadFromFile("productsResponse.xml");
        mockServer.expect(MockRestRequestMatchers.anything()).andRespond(MockRestResponseCreators.withSuccess(xml, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just follow your `withSuccess` method with `headers` method.

```
mockServer
       .expect(...)
       .andRespond(withSuccess().headers(...));
```

Answer (score 3):

@Gorazd's answer is correct.  To add more flesh to it:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setLocation(new URI(billingConfiguration.getBillingURL()+"/events/123"));
mockServer.expect(ExpectedCount.once(),
    requestTo(new URI(billingConfiguration.getBillingURL())))                    
    .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
    .andRespond(withStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).headers(headers));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following codes work for me:

```
HttpHeaders mockResponseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
mockResponseHeaders.set("Authorization", mockAuthToken);

mockServer
        .expect(once(), requestTo(testhUrl))
        .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.POST))
        .andRespond(withSuccess().headers(mockResponseHeaders));
```